# Combine RegEx and fill an underminate number of cells

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I have a cell in Excel that holds a long string in cell A1:

```
"ABC12+BED58,YZ001"
```

I have the following regex to match some specific variables in my string

```
strPattern = "[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{2,4}"
```

Basically, I need to write a macro or a function (I would prefer a function actually) that will fill cell A2, A3, A4 like that:

```
ABC12
BED58
YZ001
```

The thing is, there is an undeterminate number of parameters in the string (so for example, it could go all the way through A200).

I'm thinking of a function `get_n_variables(str, n)` that would return the Nth **unique** match

Here is my progress so far but the function returns #VALUE!

```
Function simpleCellRegex(Myrange As Range) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim matches As Object


    strPattern = "[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{2,4}"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = ""

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            Set matches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
            simpleCellRegex = matches(0).SubMatches(0)
        Else
            simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops) - see the section on splitting values.

Comment: @KenWhite I updated my question to show my progress, I believe the question is close but my code somehow is not working and I need help for the debugging

Comment: Do you have any other separators besides **+** and **,** ?

Comment: could be anything. I just need to match the variables according to the regex and then outline them in different cells in a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MrExcel Forum](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/343286-how-populate-adjacent-cells-using-visual-basic-applications-function.html):

> You can not put a function in a cell to change other cells. Functions do not work this way.

Thus, it should be a `sub`, like this, e.g. (outputs the matches under the selected cell with our input string):

```
Sub simpleCellRegex()
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Dim i As Long, cnt As Long


    strPattern = "[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{2,4}"
    cnt = 1

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = ActiveCell.Value
        strReplace = ""

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
         Set objMatches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
         For i = 0 To objMatches.Count - 1
            ActiveCell.Offset(cnt).Value = objMatches.Item(i)
            cnt = cnt + 1
         Next
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can actually still use an function if you use an array

- select `B1:D1`
- enter this formula `=simpleCellRegex(A1)` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

*if you dont know how many matches enter in more cells than there may be matches*

*code*

```
Function simpleCellRegex(StrIn As String) As Variant

    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim regMC As Object
    Dim X
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim lngCnt As Long

    strPattern = "[A-Z]{1,3}[0-9]{2,4}"

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

     With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
      If .Test(StrIn) Then
          Set regMC = .Execute(StrIn)
          ReDim X(0 To regMC.Count - 1) As String
            For lngCnt = 0 To UBound(X)
                X(lngCnt) = regMC(lngCnt)
            Next
          simpleCellRegex = X
      Else
          simpleCellRegex = "Not matched"
      End If
    End With
End Function
```